# How to find the Indices of a pixel label using a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, image-processing, matrix

I have this segmented image in which I need to find the indices of all pixels labelled ‘20’
I know I can easily do this with the code:

```
img = [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00;
       00 20 00 00 00 20 00 00;
       00 00 30 00 00 00 00 00;
       10 10 10 00 20 00 00 00;
       10 10 10 40 40 40 40 40;
       10 10 10 40 40 40 20 40;
       10 10 10 40 40 40 40 40];

[img_row, img_col] = find(img==20)
imgIdx             = sub2ind(size(img), img_row, img_col);
```

This will return a vector of all the indices of the pixels of interest. However, I would rather want to find these pixels one after the other, and I know that:

```
imgIdx = find(img==20, 1)
```

will return the index for the 1st of these pixels. Thus, is there a way to find the rest of these pixels using a loop? Any help/suggestion/advice is duly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop btw? Other than that, `imgIdx=find(img==20)` will return you the same that these two lines return: `[img_row, img_col] = find(img==20);` ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍
 `imgIdx = sub2ind(size(img), img_row, img_col);`

Comment: The best option is the way you are already doing it. Loop over the imgIdx, not over find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is not efficient to loop through an image with typically 10's of thousands to millions of elements. But if you insist, there is always a loop solution.

```
for ii = 1:numel(img)
    if img(ii) == 20
        % do_the_thing
    end
end
```

Nevertheless, even if I have to loop over `% do_the_thing`, I will do it after getting all the indices:

```
imgIdx = find(img == 20);
for ii = 1:numel(imgIdx)
    % imgIdx(ii) !!!
    % do_the_thing
end
```

Comment: @oma11, follow erfan's advise: Don't use the first code sample, use the second. Also, if it's possible to avoid the loop: Do it.

Comment: Thank you @erfan and Stewie Griffin. I doubt if the 1st solution would work, and the 2nd is almost like what I was trying to avoid. Hence, it’s best I describe a bit of what am trying to do originally.

Comment: Please see the edited version of the original post. Thanks

Comment: so sorry guys! the 2nd solution proposed by erfan worked perfectly.I just couldn't see how easy that was. I guess all it takes is a little bit of patience/time to figure these easy bits out. Thank you @erfan... am indeed grateful.